# Async event handler callback through event arguments

Tags: c#, events, asynchronous

I have a problem when I need to collect event argument data that has been changed through event hadnler that contains async calls. As you can see in code below, MessageReceiver raises event and collects data from property "Change", and continues processing. Problem is when event handler is async because it calles asny method with "await". In method OnMyEvent code continues immediately after calling the handler, it does not wait for handler to finish, so "Change" property is not set... How to make things more "in sync"?

```
public class MyEventArgs:EventArgs
{
    public bool Change { get; set; }
}

public delegate void MyEventHandler(object sender, MyEventArgs e);

public class MessageReceiver
{
    public event MyEventHandler MyEvent;

    public void RaiseEvent()
    {
        OnMyEvent();
    }

    protected void OnMyEvent()
    {
        MyEventArgs e = new MyEventArgs();
        if (MyEvent != null)
            MyEvent(this, e);
        if (e.Change)
            Console.WriteLine("Change occured");
    }
}
public class Form
{
    MessageReceiver mr;
    public Form(MessageReceiver MR)
    {
        mr = MR;
        mr.MyEvent += Mr_MyEvent;
    }

    private async void Mr_MyEvent(object sender, MyEventArgs e)
    {
        string s = await GetString();
        e.Change = true;
    }

    public async Task<string> GetString()
    {
        return await Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            return Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        }
            );
    }
}
public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MessageReceiver mr = new MessageReceiver();
        Form frm = new Form(mr);
        mr.RaiseEvent();
    }
}
```

Comment: Bacause I am writing a handler i can manage to get result from async method GetString like this:
private void Mr_MyEvent(object sender, MyEventArgs e)
        {
            string s = GetString().Result;
            e.Change = true;
        } but what if someone else writes a handler? How to wait for event handler to finish in method "OnMyEvent"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I discuss [a variety of approaches for asynchronous events](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/02/async-oop-5-events.html) on my blog. I recommend the deferral approach, which you can implement using the [DeferralManager](http://dotnetapis.com/pkg/Nito.AsyncEx.Coordination/1.0-alpha-4/net46/doc/Nito.AsyncEx.DeferralManager) and [IDeferralSource](http://dotnetapis.com/pkg/Nito.AsyncEx.Coordination/1.0-alpha-4/net46/doc/Nito.AsyncEx.IDeferralSource) types from my [Nito.AsyncEx.Coordination library](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx.Coordination):

```
public class MyEventArgs: EventArgs, IDeferralSource
{
  private readonly DeferralManager _deferralManager;
  public MyEventArgs(DeferralManager deferralManager)
  {
    _deferralManager = deferralManager;
  }
  public bool Change { get; set; }
  public IDisposable GetDeferral() { return _deferralManager.GetDeferral(); }
}

public class MessageReceiver
{
  protected async Task OnMyEventAsync()
  {
    if (MyEvent != null)
    {
      DeferralManager deferralManager = new DeferralManager();
      MyEventArgs e = new MyEventArgs(deferralManager);
      MyEvent(this, e);
      await deferralManager.WaitForDeferralsAsync();
    }
    if (e.Change)
      Console.WriteLine("Change occured");
  }
}

public class Form
{
  private async void Mr_MyEvent(object sender, MyEventArgs e)
  {
    using (e.GetDeferral())
    {
      string s = await GetString();
      e.Change = true;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Nice work with this approach, I will try to implement this in my project. So we have to be aware of "evil" async event handlers and handle these situations ourselves.